# Downloading a file using a Blob created client side does not work as opposed to when getting the Blob from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, download, xmlhttprequest, blob

Case 1)

1. Request a blob directly using XHR.
2. Save the Blob using a short func.
3. pdf/png/jpg/txt files can now be opened and viewed.

Case 2)

1. Request string using jquery.
2. Create a Blob using that string.

   ```
   var blob = new Blob([data], {
       type: appropraiteType
   });
   ```
3. Save Blob using same short func from before.
4. File now cannot be viewed properly.

I even tried a few different things. Let's say we have as a result:
xhrRequest.png and jqueryRequest.png

They both have the same mime type and character encoding. I open xhrRequest.png with a text editor and delete everything in it. Then I replace it with the content of jqueryRequest.png . xhrRequest.png still works.

The two files differ in size as did their blobs but apart from that I can't find any difference.

Any idea?

Comment: Without a proper way to reproduce your problem or the code that you are using, we can't help you.

Comment: Case 2 can only work for text files as you can't represent arbitrary binary data with a js string

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if it was even possible in the first place.